# jQuery - find element basing on the css attribute

Tags: jquery

I have that div

```
<div style='width:20px; height:20px; background-color:COLORNAME'></div>
```

which is created in the `for` loop.

Lets say I want to find the div which background color is `#0000FF`. How to do it by jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using:

```
$("[style*='background-color:#0000ff']");
```

Bear in mind, that it's based on string comparison, so spaces (and case) **will** matter.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eithe/6mwD7/

Answer (score 1):

The browser will always process the color and output it as an rgb value, so this should do:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/nbLYA/)